# Close the tab while in full screen mode on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen

Is it possible to close the current tab while in full screen mode on Chrome?

Ideally the focus would change to the other tab that is next to the closed one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> closes the current tab.

Comment: CTRL + W works.